# How do I add checks to make the code to display 'Password too short' and 'Height is not a number?'

Tags: javascript, html

I have to add checks to the `checkSubmit()` function so that it will give the following response

1. Passwords do not match
2. Passwords is too short(minimum 4 characters)
3. Height is not a number

I have managed the first one however I have no idea where to start with the other two. I'll post all the code just to be safe in case I missed something.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Form Validation</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/forms.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">

    window.onload=init;
    var form;
        function init() {
            form = document.getElementById('testform');
            form.addEventListener("submit", checkSubmit, false);
            form.addEventListener("reset", checkReset, false);

            form['colour'].addEventListener("change", checkSubmit, false);

            form['name'].focus();
        }
        String.prototype.trim=function() {
            return this.replace(/^\s+1\s+$/g, '');
        }
        function whichButton(name) {
            var buttons=document.getElementsByName(name);
            for (var i in buttons) {
                if(buttons[i].checked) return buttons[i].value
            }
            return false;
        }
        function showOtherColour() {
            document.getElementById('othercolour').style.visibility=
                form['colour'].value=='other' ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
        }
        function checkSubmit() {
            error = new Array();
            //Fill the array with the error value

            form['name'].value=form['name'].value.trim();
            form['email'].value=form['email'].value.trim();
            form['town'].value=form['town'].value.trim();
            form['state'].value=form['state'].value.trim();
            form['postcode'].value=form['postcode'].value.trim();
            form['dob'].value=form['dob'].value.trim();
            form['height'].value=form['height'].value.trim();

            //Check required fields
            if(!form['name'].value)
                error.push('Missing Name');
            if(!form['email'].value)
                error.push('Missing Email Address');
            if(!form['password'].value)
                error.push('Missing Password');

            //Check valid email address
            var pattern=/^[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$/;
            if(!form['email'].value.match(pattern))
                error.push('Invalid Email Address');

            //Check State

            //Check Post Code has 4 digits
            var pattern=/^\d{4}$/;
            if(!form['postcode'].value.match(pattern))
                error.push('Invalid Post Code');
            //Check password matches confirmation
            //var password = ;
            /*
            if(!form['passwordConfirm'].value.match(password)){
                error.push("Passwords don't match");
            }*/

            console.log(form['confirm'].value);
            console.log(form['password'].value);
            if(!form['confirm'].value.match(form['password'].value)){
                error.push('Passwords do not match');
            }

            //Check that one Gender item is selected
            if(whichButton('gender')===false)
                error.push('Please choose a Gender');

            //Check that "Other" field is filled
            if (!form['colour'].value ||
                (form['colour'].value=='other' && !form['othercolour'].value))
                error.push('Colour is not selected');

            if(error.length) { // if there are errors
            alert(error.join("\n"))
            return false;
            }
            else return true;

            //return confirm("This will submit the form"); //Temporary placeholder
        } 
        function checkReset() {
            return confirm("This will clear the form data");
        }
    </script>
<style type="text/css">
body,td,th {
    font-size: 0.9em;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="body">
    <h1>Form Validation</h1>
    <form action="http://test.miform.net" method="post" id="testform">
    <fieldset>
        <label>Name<br><input type="text" name="name" class="wide"></label>
        <label>Email Address<br><input type="text" name="email" class="wide"></label>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <label>Address<br><input type="text" name="street" class="wide"></label>
        <label>Town<br><input type="text" name="town" class="narrow"></label>
        <label>State<br><input type="text" name="state" class="narrow"></label>
        <label>PostCode<br><input type="text" name="postcode" class="narrow"></label>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <label>Password<br><input type="password" name="password" class="medium"></label>
        <label>Confirm Password<br><input type="password" name="confirm" class="medium"></label>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <label>Date of Birth<br><input type="text" name="dob" class="medium"></label>
        <label>Height<br><input type="text" name="height" class="medium"></label>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Gender</legend>
        <label><input type="radio" name="gender" value="f">Female</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="gender" value="m">Male</label>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <label>Colour
            <select name="colour">
                <option value="">Select...</option>
                <option value="black">Black</option>
                <option value="white">White</option>
                <option value="red">Red</option>
                <option value="green">Green</option>
                <option value="blue">Blue</option>
                <option value="cyan">Cyan</option>
                <option value="magenta">Magenta</option>
                <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
                <option value="other">Other</option>
            </select>
        </label>
        <input type="text" id="othercolour">
    </fieldset>
        <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Clear Form">
        <input type="submit" name="send" value="Send Off">
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This sounds like a school assignment. Also what have your tried so far to achieve all three goals? Also you could use the `minlength` attribute on the element => `minlength="4"`

Comment: Well for issue #2 - Password length - I'd just go with checking if the inputted value is less than 4 characters, if so, clear out the input and show an alert for example. And for the issue #3 - Height is not a number - you could use `isNan()` which returns true if the variable is not a number, and false if it is, where you'd include some sort of an alert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this for the second:

```
if (form['password'].value.length < 4) {
    error.push("Password is too short");
}
```

And this for the third:

```
if (isNan(Number(form['height'].value))) {
    error.push("Height is not a number");
}
```

Comment: That checks if it is Not A Number.

Comment: @DavidHendersson If my answer fixed your problem, can you mark it as accepted by clicking the grey tick mark to the left of my answer?

Comment: Just add a class: `form['password'].setAttribute("class", "invalid");` or something like that

Comment: I've been trying to make the isNan work however that bit of code is stopping the notification from popping up